# New to SSRS Configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to install and configure `SSRS` on `SQL 2005`.
When I click `Reporting Services Configuration`, I get a message saying

> No report servers were found on the specified machine - Details
>   Invalid namespace.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please refer to this specific issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dszabo/archive/2007/04/10/quot-no-report-servers-were-found-on-the-specified-machine-quot.aspx and check if it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

You don't "configure SSRS on SQL Server 2005", as such.

It's a component that you choose at install time (like Analysis Services, Integration Services etc). For SSRS, then you require IIS as a prerequsite and it won't be installed if IIS is not present.

The error itself is 100% correct if SSRS is not installed...

Is it actually installed?

Edit:

Just got this on one of my feeds: [KB 960374](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960374/EN-US) that describes the exact error above

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Vista. How can I tell if IIS is installed?

Comment: when I click on "Start -> Programs -> SQL Server 2005 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration", does that not mean that SSRS is already installed?

Comment: Start..run..services.msc. Do you have sql reporting services (or similar)?

Comment: No, so I guess its not beedn installed, correct? (not being stupid, because I recall installing it when I installed 2005)

Comment: I am installing SSRS on Vista Enterprise. How can I check if the installed SQL 2005 is x86 based OS, x64 based OS or Itanium?

Comment: The config tool is part of the client tool componenent, not part of RS. Don't know about the x84/x64 question: it won't be itanium though

Comment: "How can I check if the installed SQL 2005 is x86 based OS, x64 based OS or Itanium?" - run SELECT @@VERSION and check what it says in the brackets right after SQL's version number, for instance "10.50.1600.1 (X64)".

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. Place your disc with SQL in and run setup. Add features to your existing instance and select Reporting Services. Once installed it would have created 2 databases on your SQL Server named ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB

Open the services configuration and you should be prompted to connect to an instance of Reporting Services.

If you see this screen then you are ready to go.

--Read this only if you might have questions to ask

1. Setup a service account for Network Service (save the .snk key and it will create your IIS entries etc. If you don't have IIS then upgrade your OS to a compatible version. It can be installed via Add or Remove Windows Features)
2. Make sure your new database is selected in the Database section. If not, then follow the screen to add it
3. Open the Report Manager URL and click on the link. (You may need to be in as an administrator)
4. When you want to deploy reports, simply update your solution properties with the TargetURL pointing to the Web Service URL that is available after setting up the Service Account)

Ask anything further if you need the guidance. I've done this to about 5 servers in the past month already, so I know what can go wrong.

Cheers,